# res.json is not a function on UserService call

Tags: json, angular, observable

My application has 3 tiers of services.

- `UserService` - makes calls to `HttpClient` to perform CRUD functions for users
- `HttpClient` - a service used to validate/refresh the token is necessary, and then make a call to the `AuthHttp`.
- `AuthHttp` - a service used to make an http call and attach the token in the Authorization header

The issue that I am running into is that the `UserService` tries to map the response of the call using `.map(res => res.json()`, but I receive an error stating that `res.json is not a function`.

Here is the code for my services in order.  I will only post the "HTTP Get" related methods for brevity:

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from './http-client';
import { AddDeleteUserModel } from './AddUserModel';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  baseApiUrl = environment.api_endpoint;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAllUsers()
  {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseApiUrl + 'users').map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

**http.client.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { AuthHttp } from './authhttp.service';
import { AuthUserService } from './authuser.service';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {

  constructor(
    private authHttp: AuthHttp,
    private authUserService: AuthUserService,
    private oAuthService : OAuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  get(endpoint: string) {
    if (!this.oAuthService.hasValidAccessToken)
    {
      this.authUserService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(true);
      this.oAuthService.refreshToken().then(() =>
      {
        this.successfulTokenRefresh();
      }).catch(() =>
      {
        this.failedTokenRefresh();
        return Observable.throw("Unable to refresh token.");
      });
    }

    if (this.oAuthService.hasValidAccessToken)
    {
      return this.getInternal(endpoint);
    }
  }

  successfulTokenRefresh() {
    this.authUserService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(false);
    this.authUserService.requireLoginSubject.next(false);
  }

  failedTokenRefresh() {
    this.authUserService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(false);
    this.authUserService.requireLoginSubject.next(false);
    this.router.navigate(['/sessiontimeout']);
  }

  private getInternal(endpoint: string) {
    console.log("Getting " + endpoint);
    return this.authHttp.get(endpoint);
  }
}
```

**authhttp.ts:**

```
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, RequestMethod, Request, Connection, ConnectionBackend} from '@angular/http';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';

export enum Action { QueryStart, QueryStop };

@Injectable()
export class AuthHttp {
  process: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  authFailed: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  private _buildAuthHeader(): string {
    return "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("access_token");
  }

  public get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Rx.Observable<Response> {
    return this._request(RequestMethod.Get, url, null, options);
  }

  public post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Rx.Observable<Response> {
    return this._request(RequestMethod.Post, url, body, options);
  }

  public put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Rx.Observable<Response> {
    return this._request(RequestMethod.Put, url, body, options);
  }

  public delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Rx.Observable<Response> {
    return this._request(RequestMethod.Delete, url, null, options);
  }

  public patch(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Rx.Observable<Response> {
    return this._request(RequestMethod.Patch, url, body, options);
  }

  public head(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Rx.Observable<Response> {
    return this._request(RequestMethod.Head, url, null, options);
  }

  private _request(method: RequestMethod, url: string, body?: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Rx.Observable<Response> {
    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions(Object.assign({
      method: method,
      url: url,
      body: body
    }, options));

    if (!requestOptions.headers) {
      requestOptions.headers = new Headers();
    }

    requestOptions.headers.set("Authorization", this._buildAuthHeader())

    return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.process.next(Action.QueryStart);
      this._http.request(new Request(requestOptions))
        .map(res=> res.json())
        .finally(() => {
        this.process.next(Action.QueryStop);
      })
        .subscribe(
        (res) => {
          observer.next(res);
          observer.complete();
        },
        (err) => {
          switch (err.status) {
            case 401:
              //intercept 401
              this.authFailed.next(err);
              observer.error(err);
              break;
            default:
              observer.error(err);
              break;
          }
        })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the token is validating at `HttpClient#get(endpoint: string) {`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past. Though I did not read the entire code, I suspect it is because you do not explicitly import `Response` from `@angular/http`. I think for some reason it guesses the wrong type which does not have `.json()`.

Add at the top of your `user.service.ts`:

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http`;
```

Also add it to http.client.ts.

Make your http client signature specific:

```
  get(endpoint: string): Response {
```

Comment: I tried, but I still get res.json is not a function

Comment: `getInternal()` actually returns a `Observable<Response>`

Comment: It sure does, but the type might not be propagated . Did you try importing it explicitly in all 3 files?